# Silverlight 4 xap request is always redirected

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My Windows 8.1 development PC is having trouble loading my Silverlight 4 app, which is hosted inside of an MVC 3 website. I am able to log in to the website just fine, which uses ASP.NET's authentication framework, but when the browser attempts to load the Silverlight XAP file, it gets a 302 redirect back to the login page.

I suspect there is a problem with my IIS configuration, but I am stumped. Any hints or tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose its not directly related to SL. Focus on authentication parts.Is there any authentication for SL project or do you use asp.net membership for mvc project only? Maybe SL project doesn't see the session according to the settings. These are just my guesses from your question without much detail. I hope it helps you to focus on right part.

Answer (score 0):

[Register the MIME type](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications) for .xap in IIS. Then IIS will serve the file.

application/x-silverlight-app

Comment: Those were already configured on my dev machine. Do you have any other ideas?